# Parse an input text using Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have this corresponding input text:

```
    Clark is set to work in ''[[Superman (the Hero)|Superman]]'', a [[SuperHero Genre       II]] movie directed [[Source:NYTimes]]...
    Clark visited the [[University of Pleasantville]] campus in November 2009 to ...
    *[[1973]] &amp;ndash; [[Clark Kent]], superhero and newspaper reporter...
    After appearing in other movies, Clark starred as [[negative hero]] [[Alternate Superman]] in ''[[Superman (2003 film)|Superman]]''...
    Clark met ''[[Daily Planet]]'' reporter [[Louis Lane]]...</code>
```

This is the pattern code that I am using in Java:

```
    <code>String pattern = "(?:\\p{Punct}|\\B|\\b)(\\[\\[[^(Arch:|Zeus:|Source:)].*?\\]\\])(?:\\p{Punct}|\\b|\\B)"; 
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern); 
    Matcher m = r.matcher(data);
      while (m.find( )) {
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
      }
```

I am reading the file line by line using readLine of BufferedReader (sysout-ing every line as I parse it) and getting the following output using my regex:
    `Clark is set to work in ''[[Superman (the Hero)|Superman]]'', a [[SuperHero Genre II]] movie directed [[Source:NYTimes]]...
    Clark visited the [[University of Pleasantville]] campus in November 2009 to ...
    Found value: [[University of Pleasantville]]
    *[[1973]] &ndash; [[Clark Kent]], superhero and newspaper reporter...
    Found value: [[1973]]
    After appearing in other movies, Clark starred as [[negative hero]] [[Alternate Superman]] in ''[[Superman (2003 film)|Superman]]''...
    Found value: [[negative hero]]
    Found value: [[Alternate Superman]]
    Clark met ''[[Daily Planet]]'' reporter [[Louis Lane]]...
    Found value: [[Daily Planet]]
    Found value: [[Louis Lane]]`

As you can see the problem: I am not able to extract all the stuffs within the braces [[I_want_to_extract_these_except_Source_or_Arch_or_Zeus]]. Example: From the first line I should've extracted [[Superman (the Hero)|Superman]] etc. but it didn't retrieve anything. How can I modify my regex to extract everything except the ones which have [[Source:something]] etc.? Thank you.

Comment: append the whole text into string and then match

Comment: Is that the problem @nikolap? What is wrong by reading line by line?

Comment: I'm not sure about the all text but may have something like [[Lois Lane and on the next line closing ]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead (e.g. `(?!...)`) like this:

```
\[\[(?!Arch:|Zeus:|Source).*?\]\]
```

See it in action: http://regex101.com/r/lJ6sH3/1